# Nodejs refusing to read property of existing object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, object

I have an object from MongoDB like this:

```
var result = await dbFind.searchSongs({'name':searchTerm}); //method executed from core module
console.log(result);
/*output:
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a99a3bb26a4b92b3cd9f43c"),
        "name" : "Bad Guy",
        "artist" : "Eminem",
        "song" : "1520018363067.mp3",
        "mimetype" : "audio/mp3",
        "views" : [ ],
        "__v" : 0
}
*/
```

But when I try to access `object.property`, I get `undefined`. What is going on?

Comment: you write console.log(result.name); and get undefined?

Comment: Yes; any way to access the object returns undefined.

Comment: Can you post the output from `console.log(typeof result)`

Comment: Hmm, can you just try result.toObject()['name'] or  result.toObject().name and see if that works?